# I have to create button that will change the style of a text object in React Native App

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a button, that change textValue of a text object, but I also have to change object's style

```
this.state = { 
    login_title: 'Initial Value',
    isButtonPressed: true,
  };
      

  this.onPressButton= this.onPressButton.bind(this);
}
 onPressButton() {
    this.setState({
        isButtonPressed : !this.state.isButtonPressed,
        
        login_title : (this.state.isButtonPressed) ? 'Second Value' : 'Intial Value',
    })
}
```

...

```
<Button onPress= {this.onPressButton}>
            <ButtonText>Change Value</ButtonText>
```

```
        <Text>{this.state.textValue}</Text>
```

Comment: Okay what issue or error are you facing?

Comment: As you know set state in async process and you are doing both the things together , you should use callback in setState and then check the state of isButtonPressed and set the state of login_title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `<Text>` widget you can define the style conditionally:

```
<Text style={this.state.isButtonPressed ? styles.style1 : styles.style2}>
  {this.state.textValue}
</Text>
```

Of course, this means your style1 and style2 need to be defined.

Comment: Thank you very much.It works well.I already broke my head with this task.